# Print first line of a group of blocks after comparison of a number

Tags: bash, shell, perl

I have a many dataset  like this one:

```
1: 2.2473 0.0102
32 94.7762
33 2.17695

2: 2.9864 0.0021
32 8.42305
33 86.9749

3: 3.4679 0.0576
32 64.6138
33 32.5034

4: 3.6459 0.0531
32 62.301
33 34.7803

5: 3.8914 0.0039
35 5.04095
32 5.55511
33 4.0436 
34 82.839
```

In this example there are 5 main blocks. The first line of each block start with a number (1,2,3,4,5). The second line of a block contain another numbers, and so on ...

I need to ignore the first line of every block, and do a comparison of the numbers located at the right of the number 32, in order to choose the highest value. After that, the first line of the block, which contain the highest value  at the right of the number 32, need to be printed.

In this example, the line to be printed is :

```
   1: 2.2473 0.0102
```

I was trying to do that on bash and perl but without any success. Do you have an idea?

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with?  Do you have some code you would like to share?  Your problem statement seems well posed.

Comment: Please show us that what you have tried to do.  Otherwise the question is off-topic/too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Perl, I'd say:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$target = 32;

while (<>) {
    chop;
    if (/^\d+:/) {                  # treat the 1st line
        $firstline = $_;            # keep the 1st line
    } elsif (/^(\d+) +([\d.]+)/) {  # treat other lines in the block
        if ($1 == $target && $2 > $max) {
            $max = $2;              # update the highest value
            $maxline = $firstline;  # and the 1st line of the block
        }
    }
}

print $maxline, "\n";
```

Note that it assumes the target numbers are not negative.
Initialize $max with -Inf or whatever in such a case.

Comment: Great! This script is the real solution!

Answer (score 0):

In pure `bash` you cannot compare floats, so you have to resort to an external program. The following `awk` one-liner solves your problem. It waits for data from standard input:

```
awk '/:/{h=$0}/^32/{if($1>m){m=$1;mh=h}}END{print mh}'
```

- `h` keeps the latest block-beginning line, identified by the presence of `:`
- `m` keeps the maximum `32`-value read so far, silently initialized as `0`
- `mh` keeps the first line of the block where `m` was read

If your input data are in a file called `data.txt`

```
$ awk '/:/{h=$0}/^32/{if($1>m){m=$1;mh=h}}END{print mh}' data.txt
1: 2.2473 0.0102
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the good examples shown, here is a solution using the `reduce` function from List::Util module (which is core perl).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util 'reduce';

my $file = <<EOF;
1: 2.2473 0.0102
32 94.7762
33 2.17695

2: 2.9864 0.0021
32 8.42305
33 86.9749

3: 3.4679 0.0576
32 64.6138
33 32.5034

4: 3.6459 0.0531
32 62.301
33 34.7803

5: 3.8914 0.0039
35 5.04095
32 5.55511
33 4.0436 
34 82.839
EOF

{
    local $/ = '';
    open my $fh, '<', \$file;
    my $max = reduce {f_32($a) > f_32($b) ? $a : $b} <$fh>;
    ($max) = $max =~ /\A(.+)/;
    print $max;
}

sub f_32 {
    $_[0] =~ /^32 (\S+)/m;
    return $1;  
}
```

**Update:** to allow only one function call per block, use a cache,

```
my %c; # cache
my $max = reduce {($c{$a}//=f_32($a)) > ($c{$b}//=f_32($b)) ? $a : $b} <$fh>;
```

Comment: It looks to me like reduce has to process each block twice.

Comment: @7stud do you mean it calls `f_32` twice for every progression? If I understand `reduce`, the first block happens to be the greatest, so `f_32` gets called on that block for each iteration (4 in total) and the remaining blocks only call the function once.

Comment: Yes, that's true, and as you say you would touch block1 four times.    And, if the max was in the last block (the example I was thinking of), then except for the first and last block, you would touch every block twice.  My concern is the repetition--it seems inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering how the various solutions here measured against each other. I created a new input file of 1000 records, (rather than the 5 in the original question).

```
1: 1.0892 4.4110
33 17.46216
32 32.64771
34 112.64038

2: 9.6591 9.9243
33 116.30859
32 38.09204
34 117.57813

3: 1.6385 3.0847
33 45.08057
32 3.52173
34 145.28809

4: 7.0053 9.0564
33 24.13330
32 169.46411
34 92.74902

5: 9.9045 4.8688
33 130.81055
32 4.88892
34 54.73022

6: 0.1675 1.0004
33 11.64551
32 124.31641
34 186.35864

7: 5.5832 8.3316
33 113.65356
32 23.00415
34 85.02808

8: 5.2414 9.9789
33 37.54883
32 102.96021
34 30.73730

...

988: 1.9385 2.5787
33 40.78369
32 53.44849
34 185.05249

989: 2.5055 3.4680
33 86.19995
32 158.31909
34 34.89380

990: 2.1933 2.4203
33 197.74780
32 188.86108
34 14.01978

991: 4.7644 1.2238
33 88.16528
32 132.70264
34 24.19434

992: 8.9307 0.8044
33 139.25781
32 149.59106
34 19.18945

993: 4.4110 0.4428
33 80.05981
32 18.20068
34 95.30640

994: 2.4542 7.6740
33 80.09033
32 69.81812
34 25.07324

995: 9.3329 5.8911
33 82.72095
32 194.39697
34 95.65430

996: 0.8450 3.8217
33 32.95288
32 43.08472
34 18.46924

997: 2.0261 6.6580
33 68.61572
32 52.85645
34 136.04736

998: 2.7808 2.9456
33 54.71191
32 75.15869
34 15.55786

999: 0.6631 9.5544
33 161.90186
32 185.33325
34 61.21216

1000: 1.6800 5.0317
33 94.12842
32 188.36060
34 6.04248
```

Then, I ran a benchmark against that data.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw/first reduce/;
use Benchmark qw/ cmpthese /;

my $file = 'bench_reduce.txt';

my $cache = sub {
    local $/ = '';
    open my $fh, '<', $file;
    my %c; # cache
    my $max = reduce {($c{$a}//=f_32($a)) > ($c{$b}//=f_32($b)) ? $a : $b} <$fh>;
    ($max) = $max =~ /\A(.+)/;
    #print $max;
};

my $reduce = sub {
    local $/ = '';
    open my $fh, '<', $file;
    my $max = reduce {f_32($a) > f_32($b) ? $a : $b} <$fh>;
    ($max) = $max =~ /\A(.+)/;
    #print $max;
};


sub f_32 {
    $_[0] =~ /^32 (\S+)/m;
    return $1;  
}

my $tshiono = sub {
    my ($maxline, $firstline);
    my $max = 0;
    my $target = 32;
    open my $fh, '<', $file;
    while (<$fh>) {
        chop;
        if (/^\d+:/) {                  # treat the 1st line
            $firstline = $_;            # keep the 1st line
        } elsif (/^(\d+) +([\d.]+)/) {  # treat other lines in the block
            if ($1 == $target && $2 > $max) {
                $max = $2;              # update the highest value
                $maxline = $firstline;  # and the 1st line of the block
            }
        }
    }   
};

my $_7stud = sub {
    open my $INFILE, '<', $file;
    my %results;

    {
        local $/ = '';  #input record separator => paragraph mode

        while (my $block = <$INFILE> ) {
            my @lines = split /\n/, $block;
            my $line32 = first {/^32/} @lines;

            (undef, my $ranking_num) = split ' ', $line32;
            $results{$ranking_num} = $lines[0];
        }
    }

    close $INFILE;

    my @sorted_nums = sort{$a <=> $b} keys %results;

    my $biggest_num = $sorted_nums[-1];

};

cmpthese  (-1,
    {
        w_o_cache => $reduce,
        w_cache => $cache,
        tshiono => $tshiono,
        '7stud' => $_7stud
    });
```

For 3 runs, I got:

```
C:\Old_Data\perlp>perl bench_reduce.pl
           Rate   tshiono     7stud w_o_cache   w_cache
tshiono   132/s        --      -11%      -47%      -49%
7stud     149/s       13%        --      -40%      -42%
w_o_cache 249/s       89%       68%        --       -3%
w_cache   256/s       95%       73%        3%        --

C:\Old_Data\perlp>perl bench_reduce.pl
           Rate   tshiono     7stud w_o_cache   w_cache
tshiono   143/s        --       -9%      -42%      -45%
7stud     157/s       10%        --      -36%      -40%
w_o_cache 245/s       72%       56%        --       -6%
w_cache   260/s       82%       66%        6%        --

C:\Old_Data\perlp>perl bench_reduce.pl
           Rate   tshiono     7stud w_o_cache   w_cache
tshiono   143/s        --       -3%      -42%      -47%
7stud     147/s        3%        --      -40%      -46%
w_o_cache 245/s       71%       67%        --       -9%
w_cache   270/s       89%       84%       10%        --
```

I am guessing tshiono's took the longest time because it is reading line by line (5000 reads) rather than chunk by chunk (1000 chunks). I was surprised though, because it basically is the same logic as the `reduce` code.

7stud's result might be attributed to the sort he calls, whereas for my reduce solution doesn't sort. Although I can't say exactly.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a better example file:

data.txt

```
1: 2.2473 0.0102
35 3.21256
33 2.17695
32 64.6138   #target line

2: 2.9864 0.0021
32 8.42305   #target line
33 86.9749
34 3.44444

3: 3.4679 0.0576
33 32.5034
32 5.55511  #target line

4: 3.6459 0.0531
33 34.7803
32 62.301   #target line

5: 3.8914 0.0039
35 5.04095
33 4.0436 
32 94.7762  #target line
34 82.839
```

Code:

```
use strict;  
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;
use List::Util qw{ first }; 

open my $INFILE, '<', 'data.txt';
my %results;

{
    local $/ = '';  #input record separator => paragraph mode

    while (my $block = <$INFILE> ) {
        my @lines = split /\n/, $block;
        my $line32 = first {/^32/} @lines;

        (undef, my $ranking_num) = split ' ', $line32;
        $results{$ranking_num} = $lines[0];
    }
}

close $INFILE;
say Dumper \%results;

my @sorted_nums = sort{$a <=> $b} keys %results;
say Dumper \@sorted_nums;

my $biggest_num = $sorted_nums[-1];
say $results{$biggest_num};
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '8.42305' => '2: 2.9864 0.0021',
          '5.55511' => '3: 3.4679 0.0576',
          '62.301' => '4: 3.6459 0.0531',
          '94.7762' => '5: 3.8914 0.0039',
          '64.6138' => '1: 2.2473 0.0102'
        };

$VAR1 = [
          '5.55511',
          '8.42305',
          '62.301',
          '64.6138',
          '94.7762'
        ];

5: 3.8914 0.0039
```

The comparison operator for numbers is `<=>`, and if the things being compared aren't numbers, then perl converts them to numbers to do the comparison.  As a result, the strings are sorted as if they were numbers.